# What is this numerical method for solving Ax=b called?

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

Following is the pseudo-code of a simple iterative method of solving $Ax=b$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.

```
for i = 0 .. iteration_count
    for j = 0 .. n
        x = x + A.row(j) * (b[j] - A.row(j) * x) / (A.row(j) * A.row(j)^T)
```

Note that `A.row(j)` stands for the j-th row of A.

It seems to be neither Gauss-Seidel nor Jacobi iteration.

Does this method have a name?

Comment: (Note: this is a reply to a deleted comment.) `x` is implied to be set to an arbitrary initial guess `x0` at the start. The `x`'s are used as column vectors, so `A.row(j) * x` represents an inner product or dot product.